# Wildcards in paths for batch scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file, wildcard

I have a batch script containing a line that will recursively look in directories and copy files matching a specified filename to another directory:

```
FOR /R "J:\" %%G in (*FINAL.pdf) DO COPY "%%G" "C:\Users\user\discimport\" /Y
```

It works great. However, recently there has been a change in the file naming convention here at work and files are now no longer going to conveniently end in "*FINAL.pdf". Now they will need to be found as " *Sign_Off *.pdf". The parent directory will now end in datecode underscore final like so: "20180426_Final". I tried modifying the line in the script to what seemed logical to my non-windows sensibilities:

```
FOR /R "J:\*\*_Final" %%G in (*Sign_Off*.pdf) DO COPY "%%G" "C:\Users\user\discimport\" /Y
```

But it didn't work. I've been reading on this and can't seem to find a straight answer how to format this with the correct syntax. It appears wildcards can only be used at the end of a path. Is there a way to correctly format this using batch script or will I have to try powershell?

Comment: You can only use wildcards with the file names.

Comment: You don't need the wildcards in the path, the /R causes recursion into all the sub-directories anyway.

Comment: Did you try replacing just `*FINAL.pdf` in your 'working' script with `*Sign_Off*.pdf` or is your issue that there will be other `*Sign_Off*.pdf` files elsewhere on the `J:` drive but not in a directory name ending with `_Final`

Comment: that's correct. all directories have `*Sign_Off*.pdf` in the files there in, but I only need the ones from the ` \********_Final\ ` directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robocopy is your friend. Type `help robocopy`for a listing of its full capabilities and an explanation of the following line which should replace your for loop:

```
for /f %%G in ('dir /B /A:D *_Final') do robocopy j:\ "%%G" *Sign_Off*.pdf /MT /S /ZB
```

The `/A:D` option limits the directory listing to only directories that match the pattern and the `/B` limits the output to a simple list. You will find that robocopy is much faster than the for loop and easier to use.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that. I'll definitely be using robocopy to pare down the rest of the script. This would work 100% except I need to extract the pdfs from directories that end in "\*_Final\"... there are pdfs with the same name structure in all directories but I only need the final versions. Hope I described that understandably :)